# Git location with subdir but *not* root directory

Tags: haskell-stack

In [the manual](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#complex-package-locations-location), it says:

> A location key can be accompanied by a subdirs key to look for cabal files in a list of subdirectories as well in addition to the top level directory.

Can I have it so that I refer to a git repository and only look into a subdirectory but **not** the top level directory?

Specifically, I'm trying to get an unreleased version of a library that is part of a mega-repo, where the main library is defined in the top level directory and the dependent libraries are found in subdirectories.  I don't want to bring in the main library as it has extra changes I don't want/need yet (there is one small tweak found in the sub-library I want, but if I bring in the current state of the main library I need to bring in the entire thing due to all the unreleased version bumps).

Comment: The behavior you describe should be exactly what Stack does. Can you try it out and see if it works? Also, if you can think of a way to clarify this in the docs, a PR for such an improvement would be very welcome.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman PR submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't actually reproduce my issue when I tried again the next day.  As such, I'm not sure if there was some intermediate stage of the repository I was depending on that was broken, or if I just misunderstood the documentation and didn't actually try it (and just assumed there would be a problem).

I've tried to improve the documentation [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/pull/3190).